# Passing `this` to .keyup()

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, scope, this

**Problem:**

I am trying to use `this.str`. Is there a way to pass in `this` to the `.keyup()` function?

```
function foo() {
    var str = "some text";
    $('#inputbox').keyup(function (e) {
       alert(str); //<-- This will output "some text"
       alert(this.str); //<-- This will output "undefined"
    });
}
```

Comment: `this` in that context refers to `$("#inputbox")`. Do you want to assign a property to the function itself?

Answer (score 1):

You can store the `this` in a variable, It's common to name that variable `_this` or `_self` or `_me`.

Like so:

```js
var str = "some text";
var _this = this;
$('#button').click(function() {
  console.log(str);
  console.log(_this.str);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Click Me</button>
```

You can also use arrow functions like so:

```js
var str = "some text";
$('#button').click(() => {
  console.log(str);
  console.log(this.str);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Click Me</button>
```

You could also use some of the `Function.prototype` methods like `apply` or `call` to set `this`. But there isn't much sense in doing that in this case as you can see:

```js
var str = "some text";
var _this = this;

$('#button').click(function() {
  onKeyUp.call(_this);
});

function onKeyUp() {
  console.log(str);
  console.log(this.str);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: for me it did not work.

Comment: @user123456 Converted the code to snippets, they will all seem to work fine

Comment: I am calling foo at  ready function

Comment: Have you set `this.str` ? Because if you've never set it, you can't expect to get a value from it, other than undefined

Comment: what you mean ?

Comment: In my examples I don't need to set `this.str` because `var str` is in the global scope and in the global scope `var str` is the same `this.str`. That is only the case for the global scope. If you are not in the global scope you need to do `var str = this.str = "some text";`

Comment: @nickzooum, it worked now.

Answer (score 1):

In fact in JavaScript each `function` has its own `scope`, so inside the `keyup` callback `this` won't refer to `foo` but it will refer to the `$("#inputbox")`, which doesn't have a property called `str`, that's why you got `undefined`. This means that you can't access `foo.str` inside the `keyup` callback scope.

What you can do is to follow **the `Module` pattern code style** and to store the `str` of `foo` inside a `variable` then access it inside the `keyup` callback:

```
function foo() {
    var str = "some text";
    var _self = this;
    _self.str = str;
    $('#inputbox').keyup(function (e) {
       alert(str); //<-- This will output "some text"
       alert(_self.str); //<-- This will output "some text" too
    });
}
```

Comment: I am still getting this as window object.

Comment: @user123456 My bad, I forgot to reassign `str` to `_self`  and yes indeed `this` in this case refers to the global `window` object.